# Designing Secure Rest services

Tags: rest, api, security

Really not too sure where to go with this, I'm hoping I might get some pointers from you guys.  I'm a sole developer and I've really got no one else to ask.  I'm pretty new to all this, so I'm a little overwhelmed with info, but if there is a better place to ask this, please by all means let me know.

So the scenario is as follows.
I've written a mcv rest service that I want to consume via mobile (iOS mainly, android down the track) apps I'm also developing.
This service will be deployed to a number of IIS servers (some of which I have no control or direct access) for different customers as it is designed to integrate with local installed 3rd party software.

At the moment, security hasn't really been much of a consideration, everything is happening over http.  The nature of the data isn't very sensitive, but as I expand on the functionality I'm beginning to see a rather big security issue developing.

Initially thought that I could implement ADFS to provide the security layer, but it looks to me it's only dealing with authentication.  I don't believe that it is doing any sort transport/message security.  Going forward, authentication will be handled in the 3rd party software so I 95% confident that I can drop ADFS out of the equation anyway.

So what I'm thinking is one of two options.

1. Move to SSL and have each end user site purchase a certificate
2. Since I'm developing both ends (the service and clients) it's
   possible that I can just implement a encryption/decryption system

Or are there other options that I should consider?

Comment: Take a look at letsencrypt. It's rather new but is a pretty promising SSL alternative to purchasing a certificate. Full disclosure I'm by no means a security expert.

Comment: I deployed my MVC app to azure and it just does SSL out of the box - I didn't need to do anything. BTW you're mixing up a few security concepts here - Authentication, Authorisation and transport encryption are all different things - seems like you're only after transport encryption here. You do need to consider: can any anonymous person hit your endpoint without logging in, and make it do some work? If so you're opening yourself up to DOS attack

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  Yeah, probably am mixing this up a bit.  Yes, it is the transport encryption I'm dealing with

Comment: Well like I said Azure just did it by default - no config or certificate purchase or anything (AFAIK). I wouldn't spend any time building your own